# Websphere 8.5 bean validation error - property does not follow javabean conventions

Tags: validation, websphere, javabeans

I am using WebSphere 8.5 clustered environment and Java1.7.
I am getting error for boolean property as '**property hasXXX() does not follow javabean conventions**. 
 Code is **working** in 'Non Clustered' env correctly.
But same code **NOT working** in 'Clustered' env (and requirement is to work things in Clustered env), looks like some jar issue.
After googling found that Websphere internally has validation jar which may be overriding my application jar.Also came across 'Parent Last' option on google, but not all people were succeed with this option also.
 Can Any Websphere expert suggest in this.

Below Code I am using,

```
   @AsserTrue(groups=someruleset.class,message={some message}
   public boolean hasShortName(){ //alongwith hasShortName ,I tried with isShortName and corresponding setter,it worked in Non Clustered env.
    boolean myflag=true;
    some condition;
     return myflag;
     }
```

Comment: Maybe show some of the code in question?

Comment: @ScottKurz updated code above.Thanks in advance.